# Do I have a risk to put a thread in deadlock with std::condition_variable in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading

This is more theoretical question. I've seen couple examples with `std::condition_variable` and it seems that it gets threads to sleep until a condition will be satisfied. It is some kind of a flag on races and makes sense.

But it seems that  if a variable is always changed then a thread may be woken up for checking condition and fall asleep again, because it does not keep up to catch the situation when predicate is true and so I may put the thread in "coma".

So, is `std::condition_variable` unsafe when I use it in the such situation when I always change it?

Comment: Please include an example in the question.

Comment: you mean like signaling to a thread that it should do something and then you switch between "do something" and "do nothing" with high frequency? Just don't do it. Signal the thread once

Comment: `condition_variable`'s wait awakens when you notify it. Purpose, is that you wait till the condition is satisfied. Thus, subsequently you should notify it once the condition is satisfied (or at least has a chance to). There are also spurrous wake ups - so make sure you have an actual condition for waking up. You also need the mutex to guard the variables you change.

Comment: This is why you have to use a mutex at the same time.

Comment: @idclev Yes, I mean it. Is this situation possible?

Comment: it is possible but then either the thread that sets the condition variable is doing something wrong or the thread not waking up from the condition is a valid outcome

Comment: would be good if you turn the "theoretical question" into a specific question about code. Currently the answer would be more or less: No condition variables are not unsafe. They can be used wrong, but thats true for almost anything.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it probably is a duplicate, but duplicate of what? I can't say. It's hard to tell what you really are asking because there is no code example in your question. It's always better to show the actual code that you are thinking of instead of trying to describe it with words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be talking about some kind of 'livelock'. A deadlock is a situation where one or more threads is making no progress waiting on the release of a lock.
Livelock is similar but the state of the process is constantly changing but still none is progressing. We can also talk about 'practically livelocked' where a thread gets insufficient opportunity to make adequate progress.

To an observer livelock and practical livelock often look very like genuine deadlock.

You should design your program logic to avoid livelock. It can be non-trivial. For example many forms of lock aren't 'fair'. That is when a number of threads are waiting on a lock that is released the lock that requested it first isn't guaranteed to receive it next.

In fact many operating system locks are intrinsically unfair for example giving locks to the threads that are easier to wake up (e.g. loaded to a core and suspended) rather than harder (unloaded from a core and require reloading to resume execution).

The question doesn't give many details so it's difficult diagnose the situation.
If some particular thread (or class of thread) requires priority you might introduce a flag that tells low priority threads to not acquire the lock if a priority thread is waiting (and can run) such as `(c && !(p && priority_waiting))` where `c` is the logical condition for the low priority thread and `p` is the logical condition for the priority thread.

You should certainly avoid logic where a thread waits on a potentially transient condition.
Suppose you have some monitor thread that produces output ever 1000 cycles. A waiting condition like `(cycles%1000 == 0)` could easily miss the the counter clicking over. They should more likely to something like `(cycles-lcycles >=0)` where `lcycles` is the count of cycles last time the monitor resumed processing. That ensures the monitor will typically be given a lock that it might (for practical purposes) almost never catch.

In that example the thread is waiting for both (a) an opportunity to acquire the lock and (b) some transient condition. There's a risk that it's rare for both to occur at once and that thread may be livelocked or practically livelocked and making insufficient progress,

In short, make sure threads resume when a condition has passed not when a condition is exactly so.

You can introduce a strict queue to give threads turns. Just don't assume that is what yo have unless the documentation makes clear promises about fairness.

Answer (score 2):

This is why you also have to use a mutex whenever you use a condition variable. I think you are missing the fact that the thread starts waiting and locks the mutex *at the same time*. The thread which changes the condition must also lock the mutex when it changes the condition.

Thread 1:

```
Lock mutex
Check condition (it's false)
Unlock mutex and start waiting (these happen at the exact same time)
Finish waiting and lock mutex
Check condition (it's true)
Unlock mutex
```

Thread 2:

```
Lock mutex
Change condition
Unlock mutex
Notify condition variable
```

There is no possibility that thread 1 will wait when the condition is already true. Because the condition can't change when the mutex is locked, and the mutex doesn't get unlocked until thread 1 is already waiting.

It's possible that after thread 2 releases the mutex, but before thread 2 notifies it, thread 1 might wake up spuriously, see that the condition is true, do some other stuff, and start waiting again. Thread 2 would then notify the condition variable, and thread 1 would see it as a spurious wakeup.

Answer (score 1):

This is why a `condition_variable` is always used in combination with a lock (a `mutex`).

Both the producer and the consumer logic is performed while holding the *same* lock, so that any shared data (e.g. a queue, some condition flag, etc.) can be accessed by only one thread at a time.

Notifying a `condition_variable` happens while releasing the lock, and the waiting thread acquires the lock while waking up. So in effect, the lock is *transferred* from the producer to the consumer thread, and it is impossible to set the condition and unset it before a consumer had a chance to see it, *iff* at least one other thread is already waiting on it.

In other words, [`condition_variable::notify_one`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_one) is *guaranteed* to wake up at least one waiting thread ([`condition_variable::wait`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait)), if there is any. Of course, the producer should release the lock before or after invoking `notify_one` so as to let the waiting thread proceed.

Comment: Actually, it is preferable to release the lock _before_ calling `nofiy_one`/`notify_all`. It is not necessary to hold the mutex for the notification, and doing so causes the just notified thread to immediately block again when it tries to acquire the lock.